# Converting Specific String/Integer into Decimal

Tags: c#, variables

I want the program to get all of the `elem1`-`elem7` info, add it together, and put it into the `totalElem` variable. That part works fine.

The part I'm stuck on, is that I want to take that number (lets say `30` for example), and put it on the end of a decimal to use it as a multiplier. Therefore `30` would become `1.30`.

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'.

Please note, that is not where the variable definitions really are in the code. I just put them there so I didn't have to post my whole program.

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int startingSheetDPS;
    int chd;
    int skill;
    int elem7;
    int elem6;
    int elem5;
    int elem4;
    int elem3;
    int elem2;
    int elem1;
    int totalElem;
    decimal elemMultiplier;
    decimal baseMultiplier;

    elem1 = Convert.ToInt32(ele1.Text);
    elem2 = Convert.ToInt32(ele2.Text);
    elem3 = Convert.ToInt32(ele3.Text);
    elem4 = Convert.ToInt32(ele4.Text);
    elem5 = Convert.ToInt32(ele5.Text);
    elem6 = Convert.ToInt32(ele6.Text);
    elem7 = Convert.ToInt32(ele7.Text);
    chd = Convert.ToInt32(chd1.Text);
    skill = Convert.ToInt32(skill1.Text);

    totalElem = elem1 + elem2 + elem3 + elem4 + elem5 + elem6 + elem7;
    elemMultiplier = 1 + "." + totalElem;
}
```

In short, I want to be able to turn `elemMultiplier` into a `decimal` variable, containing `1.totalElem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a really dirty and fast way, replace your

```
elemMultiplier = 1 + "." + totalElem;
```

with

```
elemMultiplier = decimal.Parse("1." + totalElem);
```

Be ware, this is locale-dependant.

Comment: +1, exactly what I was going to say. You beat me to it by like 7 seconds :)

Comment: If you want to make it locale-independant use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator instead of dot.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
String elemMul = "1." + totalElem.ToString();
elemMultiplier = Convert.ToDecimal(elemMul);
```

Your code shows problem because "." is a string which cannot be converted to decimal implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't concatenate strings. Just do the math:

```
elemMultiplier =
  Convert.ToDecimal(1 + (totalElem / Math.Pow(10, totalElem.ToString().Length)));
```

*(Edited after Gusman noticed a problem.)*

Comment: That's completely wrong, if the sum is bigger than 100 will yield integers, that's not what he asked for.